# how do i print the value of a constructor?

Tags: javascript

i want to print bob smith and his age, how do i do this? The example is part of a object oriented series on codecademy, any help would be much appreciated.

```
function Person(name, age) {
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
};
// Let's make bob again, using our constructor
var bob = new Person("Bob Smith", 30);
var susan = new Person("Susan Jordan", 35);
// make your own class here
console.log(this.name);
```

Comment: If this is meant to be a test, why don't you take some time to learn the solution instead of asking for it around?

Comment: That's your third question about problems with the Codeacademy tasks. Maybe you have to follow the instructions or explanations more carefully. Stack Overflow is not the right place to *learn* JavaScript.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to print Bob's name, then print `bob`'s `name`:

```
console.log(bob.name);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function Person(name, age) {
    this.name = name || '';
    this.age = age || -1;
};

Person.prototype.toString = function(){
    return this.name + ' ' + this.age;
};

var bob = new Person("Bob Smith", 30);

console.log(bob.toString());
alert(bob);
```